# Search for pattern ABC and replace pattern XYZ in line

Tags: shell, pattern-matching

I have to modify contents of a text file
I wil read the file line by line and wheck if the line contains a pattern ABC
If it contains the pattern ABC, I have to replace another pattern XYZ in that line to PQR

This is the code  I made

```
while read line           
do           
    #command to search for pattern ABC. If yes, replace another pattern XYZ in this line with PQR         
done < myfilename.txt
```

Comment: Using sed is much efficient compared to while loop. I have decided to use sed in this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed, you don't need a while read loop :

```
sed -i '/ABC/s/XYZ/PQR/g' myfilename.txt
```

- `/ABC/` is the address, only lines matching this address will be processed.
- `s` is the substitution command that replace `XYZ` with `̀PQR`.
- `g` is a modifier to replace all occurrences of XYZ (`g` is for general replacement)
- the `-i` option is for applying the changes in place (the file is overwritten).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ed when the sed `-i` is not supported:

```
ed -s input <<< $',s/ABC/DEF/g\nw'
```

or

```
ed -s input << EOF
,s/ABC/DEF/g
w
q
EOF
```